# $a\equiv{b}\pmod{m},a\equiv{b}\pmod{n}\ \Rightarrow\ a\equiv{b}\pmod{lcm(m,n)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show that if $a\equiv{b}\pmod{m},a\equiv{b}\pmod{n}\ \Rightarrow\ a\equiv{b}\pmod{lcm(m,n)}$
I think this must be a basic theorem in number theory but couldn't find it in my books,also it's very useful in solving many problems concerning LCM and GCD.
Please give a proof.I have no idea for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$m|a-b$ and $\,n|a-b$ thus by definition of lcm, we can say  $[m,n]\,|\,a-b$

Comment: In fact you are saying that since $a-b$ is a common multiple of $m,n$ so it must be divisible by $lcm(m,n)$.I got it completely!! Thank you persian boy

Comment: yes, I hope the best for u

Comment: This assumes that we already know the following statement: the least common multiple is, in fact, a *multiple* of every common multiple (as opposed to merely being greater than or equal to every common multiple, which is its definition). Not a criticism, just clarifying an important step, which is probably known to the OP.

Comment: @ Greg Martin you are right

Answer (score 2):

$a=b$ mod $m$ is equivalent $a-b= cm$; $a=b$ mod $n$ is equivalent $a-b=dn$. $a-b$ is a multiple of $m$ and $n$  implies that $a-b$  is a multiple of $lcm(m,n)$. This implies that $a-b=0$ mod $lcm(m,n)$ and $a=b$ mod $lcm(m,n)$.

Comment: My problem is exactly this: How can we say $n|a-b,m|a-b\Rightarrow\ lcm(m,n)|a-b$ ???

Comment: $lcm(m,n)Z$ is the intersection of $mZ$ and $nZ$, $a-b$ divides $n$ and $m$ implies that $a-b\in nZ\cap mZ$, henceforth $a-b\in lcm(m,n)Z$ and $a-b$ is a multiple of $lcm(n,m)$.

Comment: Your answer is beyond my knowledge,but thank you

Answer (score 0):

Suppose first that $gcd(m,n)=1$, then:

$$ a-b=mnk \quad \text{ for some }k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

so is clear that $a\equiv b$ (mod $mn$).

If $gcd(m,n)=d$, so $m=p_1d$ and $n=p_2d$;

then:

$$a-b=dp_1p_2l \quad\text{ for some } l\in \mathbb{Z},$$

in particular $dp_1p_2=lcm(m,n)$ divide $a-b$, then $a\equiv b$ (mod $lcm(m,n)$).

Answer (score -1):

$a\equiv b \pmod n$ and $a \equiv b \pmod m$ is equivalent to $n|(a-b)$ and $m|(a-b)$.

Let $n=P_1^{\alpha_1}P_2^{\alpha_2}...P_k^{\alpha_k}$ and $m=P_1^{\beta_1}P_2^{\beta_2}...P_k^{\beta_k}$ (with $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ positive integers, possibly zero)

It is easy to show that $lcm(m,n)=P_1^{max(\alpha_1,\beta_1)}P_2^{max(\alpha_2,\beta_2)}...P_k^{max(\alpha_k,\beta_k)}$

We have, by hypothesis, $n|(a-b)$ and $m|(a-b)$.

Therefore, $lcm(m,n)|(a-b)$, i.e. $a\equiv b \pmod {lcm(m,n)}$